# k3s secrets.yaml produces an unexpected result after decryption

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I am taking over a k3s cluster and am trying to solve a problem with this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: clouddesktop-prod-secrets
  namespace: clouddesktop-prod
data:
  tskey: dHNrZXkta0drTWVWNkNOVFJMLVNlRkZKVFFRalM3RDgzRllvVkxCTQ==
```

... is used along with with this snippet in my deployment.yaml

```
    - name: AUTHKEY
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: clouddesktop-prod-secrets
          key: tskey
```

If I am understanding it correctly, the value under tskey will be "decrypted" and then made available as an envirnment variable called ENV_AUTHKEY.

In other words the decryption process that k3s applies will convert the encrypted value "dHNrZXkta0drTWVWNkNOVFJMLVNlRkZKVFFRalM3RDgzRllvVkxCTQ==" into a plaintext value, e.g. "tskey-abc145f" and makes it available to the runnning container as environment variable "ENV_AUTHKEY"

I have verified that indeed an environment variable called "ENV_AUTHKEY" is created, in other words that k3s appends ENV_ to the name.

But as far as I can tell the plaintext is wrong. The environment variable "ENV_AUTHKEY" is indeed created, but, it seems to not have the expected value.

Now by the documentation left for me by my predecessor, I am to create the encrypted value with this simple step:

```
echo -n "tskey-abc145f" | base64
```

So I am using base64 as the "encryption" expecting that this is what k3s expects. But the eventually decrypted value appears to me to be incorrect.

What I am trying to determine is what k3s will use to decrypt my encrypted value.

Comment: Your understanding is correct assuming you meant env variable `AUTHKEY` not `ENV_AUTHKEY`. Also, where does `plaintext` comes from ? It's not in your first two snippets. Why its in 3rd? Sorry I am unable to connect the problem statement.

Comment: It's important to note that the values in your secret are not "encrypted". They are base64-encoded cleartext; you don't need any sort of secret to read them. There is no effective difference between a ConfigMap and a Secret and Secrets are not inherently secure.

Comment: You are correct @larsks. I did put it in quotes to hint at that

Answer (score 1):

To view how kubernetes would **encode** the input string, you "may" run the following:

```
echo -n "tskey-abc145f" | base64
dHNrZXktYWJjMTQ1Zg==
```

In the following example, I am creating a secret from the command line and providing the key and value in plain text format.

```
kubectl create secret  generic  clouddesktop-prod-secrets -n clouddesktop-prod --from-literal=tskey=tskey-abc145f
```

Verify the secret and its encoded value; here, you can notice the value is encoded automatically. However, when you create a secret using a manifest file, you would have to provided base64 encoded string.

```
kubectl get secret clouddesktop-prod-secrets -n clouddesktop-prod
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: clouddesktop-prod-secrets
  namespace: clouddesktop-prod
data:
  tskey: dHNrZXktYWJjMTQ1Zg==
```

Validate that the encoded value present in the secret is decoding back to the original string(`tskey-abc145f`):

```
kubectl get secrets -n clouddesktop-prod  clouddesktop-prod-secrets -o go-template='{{.data.tskey|base64decode}}'
tskey-abc145f
```

Tested on k3s:

```
k3s --version
k3s version v1.23.3+k3s1 (5fb370e5)
go version go1.17.5
```

Comment: I discovered that my secrets.yaml was not being applied - it was in a directory that was being skipped. Once I fixed that all was well again.